# Implement `Applicative Maybe`

Tags: haskell

[Typeclassopedia](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Applicative) presents the following exercise:

> `Maybe` can easily be made an instance of `Applicative`; writing such an instance is left as an exercise for the reader.

Here's my implementation:

```
data Option a = Some a 
                | None deriving Show

instance Functor Option where
   fmap _ None     = None
   fmap f (Some x) = Some (f x)

instance Applicative Option where
   pure x                = Some x
   (Some f) <*> (Some x) = Some (f x) 
   _ <*> _               = None
```

How does this look? In particular, I'm curious if the second line of the `Applicative Option` looks good.

Should I be using `fmap` on the right-hand side instead of `Some (f x)`?

Answer (score 2):

Looks good, follows the laws of `Applicative` AFAICT, and I'd leave it like this, with `fmap` you'd need to write more.

Comment: But, by using `fmap`, I'd be re-using already written code - for `Functor Option`. Isn't that a meaningful code re-use?

Comment: Compare `fmap f (Some x)` with `Some (f x)`, I'd argue that the latter one is easier to understand, which is more important than reuse IMO.  If you had that twice or more times in a row I'd agree.